# How to escape SQL Statements while writing to sql file in python

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I want to create a SQL file with python to be executed (later) by a mysql client. How can I escape the queries string correctly?

While working on a database, I would use the connections statement function - but how can I use them for creating escaped queries in sql files?

Edit: this is an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
user = 'johndoe'
logentry = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id='5';"

with open('script.sql', 'w') as script:
    eventlog = f"INSERT INTO eventlog "\
               f"(user, timestamp, sqlstatement) VALUES "\
               f"('{user}','{now}','{logentry}');"
    script.writelines(eventlog + '\n')
```

It creates a file with the - invalid - statement: `INSERT INTO eventlog (user, timestamp, sqlstatement) VALUES ('johndoe','20220810145227','DELETE FROM test WHERE id='5';');`

As you can see, the " ' " aren't escaped - how can I get the string escaped?

Comment: Could you please add the code you have so far? Have you thought of prepared statements?

Comment: can you add the code that your worked so far and add input and expected result

Comment: Sorry! I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

The Python connector has a filter function for escaping quotes and other characters that need to be escaped.

Assuming `cnx` is a connection to your database opened by the Python Connector for MySQL:

```
logentry = cnx.converter.escape("DELETE FROM test WHERE id='5';")
```

It needs a connection to your database, because the escaping has to know about your database server's character set.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python strings are in unicode, first you need to set the correct character set in your sql file:

`SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

For escaping your unicode SQL statement you have two options:

1. The easy way - establish a connection to your database server and use driver escape function, e.g.

   import mariadb
   conn= mariadb.connect(host=localhost, .....)

   escaped_eventlog= conn.escape_string(eventlog)

In PyMySQL it is the `literal` method.

2. If you don't want to use a database driver or if you can't connect to a database write your own method for escaping, with the rules described in section Escape Sequences of [MariaDB's string literal documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-literals/)